# i found the answer!! accessing phone camera on android app when the phone has sensors off?

Tags: crash, android-camera

i have developed an android app using android studio, this app has a feature that requires using the camera to read a QR code. when i use this app on a phone that has not turned sensors off the app works normally first asking for permission to use the camera and if denied it asks again or if the access is denied completly it stops asking and goes back, however if the phone has turned sensors off then app simply crashes i tried using exceptions and it did not work. here the code part where the problem happens

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    requestcamera();

}

private void requestcamera() {
    Dexter.withActivity(this).withPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA).withListener(new PermissionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
            cs.startPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {
            Toast.makeText(Scanner.this, "permission needed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
            permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
        }
    }).check();
}
```

i tried using exceptions to solve it and i was expecting it to work the way it works when i try to open camere on facebook app or whatsapp while i am turning sensors off. it goes back and shows a toast that says "can not access camera try restarting your phone"
to keep the question short i did not upload all of my work however if need i can show it all. also the problem goes away when i comment "request camera();" in the Onresume method.
okay after a long search on the internet i found the answer.